# Android studio navigation drawer crash on press

Tags: android, kotlin

I have made a navigation drawer with Kotlin in Android Studio. When I launch my app to my phone it works like it should. But when I press the actual drawer, the app crashes. I do not know what I miss or have not made correct to make it work. If there are sertain files you need to see please let me know and I'll give it. I have tried searching on the internet but I've not come any further.
I have made an main_nav_drawer.xml file and a main_toolbar. Do I miss something here?

Comment: can you show your log and code  please

Comment: Just to add, Android Studio has a template for the drawer pattern: File -> New Project -> Navigation Drawer Activity. It could be a good starting point for a working solution that can later be customised.

Comment: @Amitpandey what code do you need to see?

Comment: @Elletlar, thanks, I'll give it a try!

Comment: Np. For a question like this, you need to attach a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and review [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Kind Regards.